# Graphical glitches after updating 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, fglrx, amd-graphics

I have a Radeon HD 7800 series card:

```
lspci -k | grep VGA -A2
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Pitcairn XT [Radeon HD 7870 GHz Edition]
Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Device e217
```

After updating to 15.04 I am getting random graphical glitches:

[image: Thanks for the Beta...]

Not a screenshot because it didn't capture the issue:

[image: Wat]

For whatever reason, this game was freaking out. Was working before the upgrade.

I have attempted to resolve the issue by uninstalling, initializing and re-installing the fglrx drivers.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep VGA -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install fglrx-updates from additional driver menu.
Start AMD Catalyst Control Center as administrator from Ubuntu menu.

Go into Display manager -> Glitch remover function (look screen) and turn it on. I stooped seeing glitches when I did that.
[image: AMD Catalyst Control Center]

Comment: for future screenshots please start the program from terminal with the command `LANG=en programname` to get (for nearly everybody helpful) english screenshots. **;-)**

Comment: Will give this a shot, and accept if it works.  Unfortunately, sometimes a few hours of usage is required for windows to start glitching out.